# Gridview Button Functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I connect a button to a function in C#, ASP?
Maybe something like:

```
    <TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Button ID="btnFunction1" runat="server CommandName="Function1"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </TemplateField>
```

C# Class:

```
    protected void Function1()
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on what you want to do...if you want to process a GridView command use the `OnRowCommand` event instead...

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" OnRowCommand="grid_RowCommand">
<Columns>
   <TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Button ID="btnFunction1" runat="server CommandName="Delete"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then on code-behind....

```
protected void grid_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
}
```

But if you want to simply handle the button's click event then, register the event declaratively using the `Click` event...

```
<TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="btnFunction1" runat="server OnClick="Function1"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</TemplateField>
```

and adjust your event handler method to match the same method signature of the `Click` event...

```
protected void Function1(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
}
```

Comment: OnClick and its handlers are what I just need. Thanks!